# How to export figures with normal spacing in texts?

Tags: plotting, export, text, pdf-format

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, and I use MMA 10.

I export a figure ploted in MMA to a pdf file and then import the pdf in Latex, here is the screenshot
[image: odd]

As you can see, the spacing in the text is odd. But it becomes normal if the length of each word is not too long.[image: normal]

So, how to fix this problem if there is a long word in the figure? How can I export it to a pdf file properly?

Here is the code to plot the figure

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{"notethesaapa c in g"}, {Scaled[{0.9, 1.0}], {0.9, 1.0}}], 
  FrameLabel -> {None, None, "note the saapa c in g" , None},Frame -> True]
```

PS: I check in Windows and Mac OS, there is no probelm.

Comment: Please tell us about your OS, your _Mathematica_ version and provide a small code producing the issue.

Comment: Why do not you insert a few additional empty intervals between the words "note", "the" and "saapa"? This seems the easiest, unless you have in mind a high-quality image as eg., for a journal publication.

Comment: @Öskå Thanks! I update the quaestion. My OS is ubuntu 14.04 and I use MMA 10.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It's just an example to show the problem. There are many long word in English, for example, 'smiles': there is a mile between two 's'.

Comment: I tried your example in two ways at Mma 10.0, Win7. The first was to use the Menu/File/SaveSelectionAs, the second one to export the file. In the both cases I saved the files as pdf ones. I did not observe any fusion of the words in the FrameLabel.

Comment: So the first image is a printscreen of the PDF and the second is a printscreen of _Mathematica_? `Export["~/test.pdf", p]` works fine for me on Fedora.

Comment: @Öskå Yeap. Thanks! I use `Export["~/test.pdf", p]` with the same problem. So, it's a question of Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes, I also tried on Windows with no problem. So, it may be only a question with Ubuntu.

Comment: @EdenHarder Would it work with `FrameLabel -> {None, None, "note" <> "\[ThinSpace]" <> "the" <> "\[ThinSpace]" <> "saapa" <>    "\[ThinSpace]" <> "c" <> "\[ThinSpace]" <> "in" <> "\[ThinSpace]" <> "g", None}`?

Comment: @Öskå I'm sorry, nope.

Comment: @EdenHarder Then I can't help :( I don't see anything else than this :)

Comment: @Öskå Thanks all the same!

Comment: Eden, does `FrameLabel -> {None, None, Pane["note the saapa c in g"], None}` work?

Comment: @kguler Thanks! not works. Everything is Okay in MMA, but the question occurs when export the figure to a pdf file.

Comment: Can you specify the precise version of Mathematica you have? I cannot reproduce the problem with Mathematica 10.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.10.  I couldn't try 10.0.2 or 10.1.0.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! Mathematica 10.0.0.0, Ubuntu 14.04. Maybe I should upgrade all of them.

Comment: May be [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135321/280) approach can help?

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that the "Save Graphic As..." option doesn't work very well for exporting to PDF. Maybe try exporting to an image file type like png or jpg first and then convert to PDF with an external tool. Or simply *print* to PDF within Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: Thanks！`Print` is not OK also.

Comment: Are you interested in this because you want to import the graphics in a LaTeX document? If so, I could write a step-by-step guide on how to use the **psfrag** package to get LaTeX to render the text inside an imported image.

Comment: Yeap, you got me. Thanks so much! Even the coordinates in the axis will be mixed up when I export the figure as a eps file.