# EMF Export text spacing defect

Tags: export, output-formatting

How can I fix the EMF text spacing in Mathematica 11?

For example

```
Export["an.emf",
  a = Graphics[{{Yellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {240, 30}]},
     {Black,
      Inset[Style["Information table example",
        FontSize -> 20], {0, 15}, {Left, 0}]}},
    BaseStyle -> FontFamily -> "Franklin Gothic Book",
    ImageSize -> 240, PlotRange -> {{0, 240}, {0, 30}}]];
Print[a]
```

[image]

The EMF produced by Mathematica 11 has irregular spacing

[image]

On the same PC Mathematica 7 produces the expected result

[image]

I am running Mathematica 11.0.1 and 7.0.1 on Windows 10 Pro.

**Edit**

Here is a better example to further illustrate the problem.

These tables were produced with the code below.  Displayed in Mathematica they look fine.

First using the font "Franklin Gothic Book", then "Verdana".

[image]

However, **when exported to EMF there are spacing problems.**

[image]

1. There is a big space between "Information" and "table" in the Franklin Gothic Book version.
2. big spaces in "Category Item Text".
3. irregular space between 1,234 and ,567.00
4. big space between 123.456 and % which shouldn't be there at all
5. big space between (123.120 and ) which shouldn't be there
6. In the Verdana version no space in "CategoryItem" and no space in "CategoryText".
7. the % and closing bracket in (123.12) are squashed to the preceding character.

As I mentioned earlier, the EMF exports from Mathematica 7 look perfect.

Code

```
a = Graphics[{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{-1,-60},{740,25}],
{{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{0,0},{739,25}]},
{Black,
Inset[Style["Information table example",FontSize->16,FontSlant->Italic],
{0,43/3},ImageScaled[{0,1/2}]]}},
{{GrayLevel[0.3],Rectangle[{0,0},{739,-35}]},
{GrayLevel[1],
{Inset[Style["Category Heading Text",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{6,-35/4},ImageScaled[{0,1/2}]],
Inset[Style["",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{6,-105/4},ImageScaled[{0,1/2}]]},
{{Inset[Style["First Column",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{190,-35/4}],
Inset[Style["Part One",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{190,-105/4}]},
{Inset[Style["Column Two",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{306,-35/4}],
Inset[Style["Part Two",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{306,-105/4}]},
{Inset[Style["%",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{404,-35/4}],
Inset[Style["",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{404,-105/4}]},
{Inset[Style["Column 4",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{989/2,-35/4}],
Inset[Style["",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{989/2,-105/4}]},
{Inset[Style["",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{1199/2,-35/4}],
Inset[Style["Type",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{1199/2,-105/4}]},
{Inset[Style["",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{1393/2,-35/4}],
Inset[Style["% Total",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{1393/2,-105/4}]}},
Inset[Style["Summary",FontSize->12,FontSlant->Italic],{642,-35/4}]}},
{{{GrayLevel[0.9],Rectangle[{0,-35},{739,-57}]},{Black,
Inset[Style["Category Item Text",FontSize->12],{6,-46},ImageScaled[{0,1/2}]],
{Inset[Style["1,234,567.00",FontSize->12],{233,-46},ImageScaled[{1,1/2}]],
Inset[Style["Category Text",FontSize->12],{349,-46},ImageScaled[{1,1/2}]],
Inset[Style["123.456%",FontSize->12],{429,-46},ImageScaled[{1,1/2}]],
Inset[Style["(123.120)",FontSize->12],{530,-46},ImageScaled[{1,1/2}]],
Inset[Style["Category Text",FontSize->12],{639,-46},ImageScaled[{1,1/2}]],
Inset[Style["10.7",FontSize->12],{724,-46},ImageScaled[{1,1/2}]]}}}},{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{652.9,-35},{655.1,-123}]},
{{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{130.9,0},{133.1,-123}]},
{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{246.9,0},{249.1,-123}]},
{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{362.9,0},{365.1,-123}]},
{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{442.9,0},{445.1,-123}]},
{GrayLevel[1],Rectangle[{543.9,0},{546.1,-123}]}}},
BaseStyle->FontFamily->"Franklin Gothic Book",ImageSize->739,
PlotRange->{{0,739},{-59,25}}]

Export["a.emf", a]
```

Comment: Actually, I have difficulties seeing the difference in spacing in the images you provided. I do see a font or magnification difference, but that may be due to different Frontend settings?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The space between "Information" and "table" is double-width. It looks pretty poor on a full full table, with irregular spacing all over the place, not to mention other problems with characters fixed by editing FontMap.tr.  Not sure how to fix the spacing problem.  Seems to be a font substitution error.

Comment: Font map edit fixed awful EMF rendering of % and ( ). [Link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78893/363)

Comment: What version of MS Word do you use? I get much better results with Word 2003 on Windows 7 x64, but when I right-click on the imported figure and choose **Edit picture** and then close the edit window, I get something very similar to yours. So it may be a problem with your version of Word in the first place. Please try to open your EMF file with [EMFexplorer](http://frazmitic.free.fr/emfexplorer/) and post the screenshot (here is what I get: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhDRO.png)). From the other side, it also may be an OS-dependent issue.

Comment: We are using MS Office 2010, Word 14.0.7177.5000 (32-bit) and  Mathematica 11.0.1 running on Windows 7 and 10.  Attaching EMFexplorer screenshots to my answer.

Comment: Tangentially related: "[General PDF/EMF export problems and solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6124065/590388)."

Answer (score 1):

To make the EMF look OK when imported into Word use

```
Export["a.emf", a, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

This makes the EMF big, and the increased resolution isn't necessary in Mathematica 7 EMFs, but it fixes the appearance.

Font map editing was also required to fix the EMF rendering of % sign and brackets, as detailed here: [Wrong font selection for some characters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78893/363).

*Word screenshot*

[image]

*EMFexplorer images*

1. [Default resolution & original font map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWAp6.png)
2. [Resolution set to 300 & original font map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xorbj.png)
3. [Resolution set to 300 & edited font map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMAie.png)

The % and ( ) font issues don't show up so much in EMFexplorer but they certainly show in Word and Paint (the default app from EMF on Windows).

Comment: (+1) I have checked this solution with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.0.0 on Windows 7 x64, it works! Obviously the problem is here at least starting from version 8.0.4.

Comment: Thanks for checking the other versions Alexey.